# How to find all the files created today and modified anytime before 5 minutes?

Tags: linux, bash, find

Let's say it is 10:00 am when the command is run, I need to list the files modified between midnight and 9:55 am.

I have tried the following command which looks logical as per the documentation but it is pulling all the files since yesterday.

```
-rw-r----- 1 anami anami 0 Jan 26 17:51 a
-rw-r----- 1 anami anami 0 Jan 26 18:18 b
-rw-r----- 1 anami anami 0 Jan 26 01:00 c
-rw-r----- 1 anami anami 0 Jan 25 10:00 d
-rw-r----- 1 anami anami 0 Jan 27 12:21 e
-rw-r----- 1 anami anami 0 Jan 27 12:52 f


$ find . -daystart -mmin +5

./a
./g
./d
./c
./e
./b
./f
```

Comment: Looking at your question history, if somebody answers your question. Please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) any answers that might have helped you. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: @0stone0 I am sorry, I clicked the Up arrow yesterday and though that is enough. Done it right way now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `-daystart` isn't that portible, consider a solution like so;

1. Use `$(date +"%H")` [to get the current hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361982/get-current-time-in-hours-and-minutes), in your test case, this should be **`10`**.
2. Multiply that number by **60** to get the desired *minutes*
3. Subtract 5 minutes to get the number of minutes between 00:00 and 09:55
4. Use that value for the `-mmin` param

```sh
currentHour=$(date +"%H")
minutes=$(( 60 * currentHour - 5 ))
find . -mmin "-${minutes}" -mmin +5
```

Comment: It worked with a little change - find . -mmin "-${minutes}" -mmin +5

Comment: Ahh, you're right, you need a `-`. However, the second `-mmin`, is that really needed if you subtract 5 minutes? Either way glad it worked ;)